# Access VBA for Saving data entered in Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, savechanges

When a user closes the form, Access automatically saves the data entered in database. Thus there is no need to having a Save Button.

But, since most of the users are so habitual in pressing `Save` button, they will still insist that there should be a `Save` Button.

What code should be written for the `Save` button for saving all the data entered in the form.

Also care has to be taken for checking if the data has changed or not. Sometimes users will open the form to view data, then even though though they have not made any changes, they will press `Save` Button.

Comment: Would this code work for you? `Private Sub cmdSave_Click() : Msgbox "Data Saved", vbOkOnly : End Sub` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Dirty` only:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for Click event of `Save` Button

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    If Me.Dirty Then    'to check if any data has changed.
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is what you want based on the same comments that i got from my colleagues... I always begin with asking a question whether they want to save or not, sometimes users are just playful and mess around with records.

```
    If me.dirty = true then
            If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save as " & TempVars!gbl_username    & "? 
                       After saving you will be moved to a new record", _
                       vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Save Changes") = vbNo Then
                'If answer is no
                    'Do nothing
            Else
               DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70                    
            End If
    End If
```

Comment: Microsoft deprecated `DoCmd.DoMenuItem` twenty years ago.  They recommend `RunCommand` instead.